# How to get ApplicationContext in xml definition?

Tags: java, spring

What is the xml equivalent of the

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;
```

?

P.S.: When I try to google it I got a million results about how ApplicationContext  works but not how to get it in the xml definition. The project is all writen using xml definition so I need to find a way how to do it without anotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, configure your spring beans in file applicationContext.xml
For example:-**

```
        <bean id="beanId"
            class="com.java.spring.MyClassName">
        </bean>
```

**load the spring configuration file and retrieve bean from spring container**

```
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    

        MyClass myBean = context.getBean("beanId",MyClass.class);
```